# Need to add a class name to an element in colorbox window, using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using `colorbox.js` to create a modal window:

I just need to add the classname 'colorbox-form' to the element with the id #colorbox when it is loaded on the page.

This is the javascript for the trigger.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                 $(".modal").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#inline_contact" });
});
```

The colorbox.js can be found here:
http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/#click

and here's the html for the colorbox when it's loaded:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 122px; padding-right: 122px; opacity: 1; cursor: auto; position:     absolute; display: block; width: 669px; height: 435px; top: 700px; left: 436px; " id="colorbox" class="">
<div id="cboxWrapper" style="width: 791px; height: 557px; ">
    <div style="" id="mf0">
        <div id="cboxTopLeft" style="float: left; ">

        </div>
        <div id="cboxTopCenter" style="float: left; width: 669px; ">
        </div>
        <div id="cboxTopRight" style="float: left; ">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left; " id="mf1">
        <div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 435px; ">
        </div>
        <div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 669px; height: 435px; ">
            <div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 669px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; height: 407px; ">
                <p>content</p></div>
            <div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" style="height: 435px; display: none; " class=""></div>
            <div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" style="height: 435px; display: none; " class=""></div>
            <div id="cboxTitle" style="display: block; " class=""></div>
            <div id="cboxCurrent" style="display: none; " class=""></div>
            <div id="cboxNext" style="display: none; " class=""></div>
            <div id="cboxPrevious" style="display: none; " class=""></div>
            <div id="cboxSlideshow" style="display: none; " class=""></div>
            <div id="cboxClose" style="" class="">close</div></div>
        <div id="cboxMiddleRight" style="float: left; height: 435px; "></div></div>
    <div style="clear: left; " id="mf2"><div id="cboxBottomLeft" style="float: left; "></div>
        <div id="cboxBottomCenter" style="float: left; width: 669px; "></div>
        <div id="cboxBottomRight" style="float: left; "></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; display: none; " id="mf3">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you "just need to add a class" can't you do $("#colorbox").addClass("colorbox-form") in the document ready? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: write `$("#colorbox").addClass("colorbox-form")`

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick :)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#colorbox").addClass("colorbox-form"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to add this code:

    $("#colorbox").addClass("colorbox-form");
 
onto the trigger code:
   $(document).ready(function(){
                 $(".modal").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#inline_contact" });
    });
 
So the trigger opens the lightbox, and also adds in the classname, I can't work out how to add the two together!
 
I'm using the colorbox for two different things on the same page, so the background needs to be grey for one, and white for the other one.
 
There are different trigger codes for each type of colorbox

Comment: Thanks, have got it to work! I added the addclass code to the trigger html link:
    <a href='$("#colorbox").addClass("colorbox-form");' class='modal'>Say hello</a>

Comment: This will add the class for instances of Colorbox on a page. If you want to add the class on a case-by-case basis (for example, to style individual Colorbox popups), @soupenvy's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

This will add a custom class to your #colorbox window:

```
$('.my-box').colorbox({className: 'my-class'});
```

Comment: Make sure that your colorbox version is 1.3.27 or higher. The className property isn't available in previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

The colorbox plugin provides several callback functions http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Here's a sample of adding a class via the **onOpen** callback:

```
$('.js-colorbox').colorbox({
    width: '50%',
    onOpen:function(){
        // add unique class
        $('#colorbox').addClass('cboxLoadedContent-alt');
    },
});
```